# what are the two parts of a binary called?

Tags: word-usage

How would you fill in the blank for the sentence "Some people do not want to conform to one ______ of the gender binary." All the words I can think of imply a spectrum, rather than two options (pole, extreme, end, etc.)

Comment: What's a binary? How does one conform to it?

Comment: Normally the two parts of binary are called one and zero.  "Binary", by itself, refers to the base-2 numeral system.  Its use has not, so far as I know, been extended in the way you are attempting to use it.  You may want to re-word it to something like "some people do not want to conform to a binary classification."

Comment: _Binary_ is an adjective and normally modifies a noun. This (rather stupid) exam question has promoted it to a noun by not mentioning what it modifies -- _roles, choices, types, characters, identities, identifications,_ or whatever -- and therefore created an ungrammatical sentence that can't be improved by filling in the blank.

Comment: @Hellion - With binary stars I doubt that one is called "zero" and the second "one".

Comment: @JohnLawler you're overlooking the quite standard use of [*binary*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/binary) as a noun. There's no failure in grammar here. It's an interesting question.

Comment: Elisha, did you look up the word in some dictionaries? We expect people to do a bit of research before asking here, and to explain what they found and why it hasn't solved the problem. There are several obvious candidates, starting with the neutral "choice", "option" or "item" or, referencing the pairing, "twin", or less neutral "assignation" or "opposite". Try looking these up in a thesaurus for further alternatives...

Comment: @Chappo thanks. I did look up the word binary and sentences that were in definitions, and also googled how people used it, but couldn't find anything that conformed to what I needed. None of the words that I included in the parens seemed to imply two possibilities for gender, and that's what I needed to convey. I think assignation could work. Thank you.